# Is there a way that can convert extension method into property?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

The problem comes from two requirements:

1. I'm extending a class (from somewhere else without source code) using extension methods.
2. I'm going to bind it to a property of windows form control which requires exactly a property.

So there's my current code:

```
public static class SomeClassExtender
{
    public static string GetSomeProp(this SomeClass instance) { ... }
    public static void SetSomeProp(this SomeClass instance, string value) { ... }
}

public class SomeClassWrapper
{
    private SomeClass instance;
    public SomeClassWrapper(SomeClass instance) { this.instance = instance; }
    public string SomeProp 
    {
        get { return this.instance.GetSomeProp(); } 
        set { this.instance.SetSomeProp(value); }
    }
}
```

These code definitly works, but however I'm interested in if there is a better way to accomplish this, may be attributes or something?

Comment: Better to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why don't you subclass SomeClass ?

Comment: Many of the methods in the external library returns this class. I think it's tedious to convert every of them into subclass.

Comment: @brz I would strongly advice against subclassing outside components. It introduces way too high coupling to parts you don't have control over. Wrapping and delegation - as done by the above example - allows using the external component without creating an entangled mess that you'll never be able to decouple again. I personally like OP's approach.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth using T4 text templates to generate wrapper code.